# Warning the script isympy.exe is not on path

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I got this message when I downloaded sympy.
[image]

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: Have you read the message?  It gives you two alternatives.  "Adding this directory to the PATH"  or "use --no-warn-script-location" when installing.

Comment: @ewong is there a command to add it to a path?

Comment: you add it to your path. via  ```set PATH=<that path>;%PATH%```  but that's only during the particular terminal session.. to make it more permanent, include that in your system's environment PATH statement..  that said,I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do.